# Search several lists for object with specific title

Tags: c#, winforms, list, object

I need to go throughout 3 lists with objects. Each object in each list has same structure. And  each object inside a list has a title `_objectTitle`

These are my lists

```
List<Example> exampleList_1;
List<Example> exampleList_2;
List<Example> exampleList_3;
```

therefore I need to go through all lists in a for loop so `exampleList_1[i] exampleList_2[i]` ..etc and see if there is and object in one of them that has `_objectTitle` equal to a `"string string string"` In this case all titles are unique and there can be only one object returned.

Comment: Note that if you have a number of lists that are all related in such a way, you might want a collection of lists - if you literally have numbered variables like this, you almost definitely want a collection of lists.

Comment: @Lattyware am new to programming, if it will make an answer simpler, could you explain how to make collection of lists and thus achieve what I am asking in a question?

Comment: @GrantWinney no, just an example title can be anything like "This is my title blah blah" I wanted to show that there can be several words in it.

Comment: The same way you'd make any other collection - if you wanted a list of lists, as would be appropriate here, you just have `List<List<Example>> ...`.

Comment: @Lattyware Ah awesome, yes I can see how this is useful here, will try to use it.

Answer (score 0):

You can search all three at once by [concatenating the lists](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb302894%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) together before search for the title:

```
var example = exampleList_1.Concat(exampleList_2)
                           .Concat(exampleList_3)
                           .SingleOrDefault(x => x._objectTitle == "someTitle");
```

You can use [`SingleOrDefault()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb342451%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) since the titles are unique and at most you expect one match.

If a title is not found, then `example` will be `null`.

Answer (score 0):

If the items are in 3 different lists, the easiest way to do it is with the [Concat()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb302894%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) method.

```
var found = exampleList_1.Concat(exampleList_2).Concat(exampleList_3).SingleOrDefault(e => e._objectTitle == "string string string");
```

This will return a single item with the Title set to "string string string", or NULL if it's not found.